# How to convert hexadecimal to decimal in assembly language

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, mplab

I need to convert from hexadecimal to decimal in assembly language MPLAB, the problem is that I don't know how to represent the decimal digit in the file registers, it works fine from `0` to `9` but `0A` is `10` in decimal, so in the file register show `0A` as well. I'm using `D'10'` to represent decimal numbers but it's not working

Example:

```
Nine
 movlw  d'09'
 movwf  0x0D
```

how could I see this '`09`' in `0x0D` as well?

Comment: Can you include code to show what you have attempted at first?

Comment: define what you mean by decimal and hexadecimal in writing or by way of an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the the tab 'Window/debugging/Watches' you could right click on any value displayed here and select between hexadecimal and decimal.